# Android No internet access on Emulator, proxy settings?

Tags: android-emulator

Previously I was using proxy settings and I was able to access internet from browser as well as browser on Emulator. Now I don't use any proxy and I am able to access internet from browser but I no longer get internet access inside the emulator. Also, I'm using Linux so there's no concerns with a firewall, and I've checked for proxy settings in command mode while running emulator with `emulator -avd AVDName -verbose`.

Answer (score 2):

yup i've got the solution, at first it was proxy and then DNS server, we need to set DNS server. Here are the steps that you can set your DNS server

- on command line **emulator -avd AVDName -dns-server: 8.8.8.8 -verbose** . Here verbose is to see the processes in command mode while running emulator
- In eclipse *Run>Run Configurations>select target tab* and then in field Additional Emulator Command lines type **-dns-server: 8.8.8.8**

Comment: thanks this was the final piece in my jigsaw.. I have compiled my findings at    http://learnplusplus.blogspot.com/2012/06/proxy-settings-for-google-maps-on.html